# Styling select field and options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a multi select field with a bunch of options that i want to display as small blocks rather than having a long list of items. I can do this by setting the "option" to "display: inline-block" however i get a problem where the options dont go into a second line when reaching the container border but get hidden behind the container.

[image]

As you can see here the last item us cut off and all following items are not visible.

```
.column-select {
    width: 100%;
}
.column-select option {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #2b3035;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 5px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Is there any way to have the options pass into the second line instead of going behind the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem possible to do this with the select element. I changed the field structure from `"select>options" to "ul>li>checkbox"` so I can style the box the way I want and each `li` as well. After hiding the checkbox with `"appearence: none"` the result is the same as with the select.

Answer (score 0):

By giving the style `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container, the options will automatically wrap to the next line when they reach the containers width limit.

Here is the updated CSS code:

```
.column-select {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column-select option {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #2b3035;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: display: flex; on parent negates the display: inline-block; on option's (children) so they are all displayed in a list.